# Does anyone know how to make Required fields work on Safari 5

Tags: html

I am a newbie when it comes to the web development. I am creating a form and in the `input` tag I added the `required` attribute. It works on every browser except for safari5. After doing some research I found that the `required` attribute is not supported by Safari 5. Any suggestions as to what I should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see [here](http://caniuse.com/form-validation), form validation isn't fully supported in Safari, IE9 and earlier, and some mobile browsers. You will need to look into a fallback solution for those situations. These fallbacks are typically called polyfills.

HTML5 Please has some recommended polyfills for form validation: http://html5please.com/#form%20validation

One final thing to remember, even if you do client side validation, always do server side validation as well because you should never blindly trust data coming from the user.